# Web elements extraction from websites using Python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, urllib2, xml.etree

I want to extract various elements from tables and paragraph texts from this website.

https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655

This is the code I am using:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import urllib2
source = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30656&SSO=1').read()
x = etree.HTML(source)
growth = x.xpath("//*[@id="home_feature_container"]/div/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/p)")
growth
```

What is the best way to extract the elements I want from a website without having to change the XPath in the code every time? They publish new data in the same website every month, but the XPath seems to change a little bit sometimes.

Comment: What are the elements you want ? your XPath is not valid and can't be tested on this page.

Comment: I have changed the xpath. I need elements from the 'Manufacturing at a glance' table. And also the paragraph text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position of the items you want changes regularly, try to retrieve them by name. Here is, for example, how to extract the elements from the table in the "New Orders" row.

```
import requests #better than urllib
from lxml import html, etree

url = 'https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655&SSO=1'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

neworders = tree.xpath('//strong[text()="New Orders"]/../../following-sibling::td/p/text()')

print(neworders)
```

Or if you want the whole html table :

```
data = tree.xpath('//th[text()="MANUFACTURING AT A GLANCE"]/../..')

for elements in data:
    print(etree.tostring(elements, pretty_print=True))
```

**Another example using BeautifulSoup**

```
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655&SSO=1"

content = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

table_body = table.find('tbody')

data= []
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data)
```

Comment: Hey Ettore, there was a small problem. I have described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42592948/4399016
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to the rescue:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
soup.find('div', {'id': 'home_feature_container'}, 'h4')
```

This code is on its way to fulfilling the spec as described. If you use `soup.find().contents`, it created a list of each item contained within the element.

As far as accounting for changes on the page, it really depends. If the changes are dramatic, you would have to change `soup.find()`. Otherwise you may be able to write code that is general enough that it will always apply. (Like if the `div` called *home_feature_container* is always featured, you would never have to change that.)

Comment: Hi, could you show an example of code that returns some value. There is a table 'MANUFACTURING AT A GLANCE'. Could you show some element being extracted and displayed with your technique. Thanks a Ton!!